# Reference or counterexample: simplicial algebra isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory, model-categories

I'm looking for either a reference, a quick proof, or a counter example to the following claim:

> Let $R_{\bullet}$ and $T_{\bullet}$ be simplicial $k$-algebras. Let $S_{\bullet}$ be the polynomial resolution of $R_{\bullet}$; that is, $S_{i}:=k[k[k[\cdots[k[R_{\bullet}]]\cdots]]]$, iterated $i$ times. Is it true that
> \begin{align*}
> \pi_{n}(\operatorname{Hom}_{s\mathbf{Alg}_{k}}(R_{\bullet},T_{\bullet}))\cong\pi_{n}(\operatorname{Hom}_{s\mathbf{Alg}_{k}}(S_{\bullet},T_{\bullet})),
> \end{align*}
> where $\operatorname{Hom}_{s\mathbf{Alg}_{k}}(-,-)$ has the structure of a simplicial set, and thus we may take its homotopy groups. If not, are there simple hypotheses one can put on $T_{\bullet}$ that would guarantee this?

I suspect it could be true, because the corresponding statement is true in the homotopy category, thanks to the fact that we localize at weak equivalences. That is, $\operatorname{Hom}_{Ho(s\mathbf{Alg}_{k})}(R_{\bullet},T_{\bullet})\cong\operatorname{Hom}_{Ho(s\mathbf{Alg}_{k})}(S_{\bullet},T_{\bullet})$ because $R_{\bullet}\cong S_{\bullet}$ in $Ho(s\mathbf{Alg}_{k})$.

Comment: Why do you say the hom is a simplicial algebra? It can be empty if, for example, $R$ is the zero algebra and $T$ is not. Putting that aside, there is no reason to believe that the underived hom functor preserves weak equivalences in such generality either – there would be no point in derived hom functors otherwise.

Comment: @ZhenLin yes, the specific use I’m interested in wouldn’t have the zero ring but that’s a great thing to be aware of. Do you have a specific counter example to the claim then? That would provide a good answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry, specifically a counter example that isn’t the zero ring, a more nontrivial example. :)

Comment: If it is helpful, I also know that $S_{\bullet}\to R_{\bullet}$ is a cofibrant replacement.

Comment: First things first: the hom functor takes values in simplicial _sets_ at best, not simplicial algebras. What I said before still applies – if you think about how derived functors are calculated you would see it would be meaningless if cofibrant replacements map to weak equivalences.

Comment: @ZhenLin, is there not an internal hom functor in s\mathbf{Alg}_{k}$? Regardless, taking values in simplicial sets should be okay for me; as long as they are all fibrant I can still compute homotopy. And I’m sorry, I don’t follow “it would be meaningless if cofibrant replacements map to weak equivalences” - is a cofibrant replacement not by definition also a weak equivalence between the object and its replacement?

Comment: There is no internal hom in simplicial algebras, no more than in ordinary algebras. I advise you to think about the dual scenario in simplicial sets: the covariant hom functor does not map fibrant replacements to weak equivalences in general; if it did then the derived hom functor would coincide with the underived hom functor but it does not.

Comment: @ZhenLin I see, thank you. Are there any conditions on $R_{\bullet}$, $S_{\bullet}$, and $T_{\bullet}$ that would give the isomorphism of $\pi_{n}$? In particular, say $R_{\bullet}$ is any simplicial $k$-algebra, $S_{\bullet}$ is the polynomial resolution (example on page 7-8: http://math.uchicago.edu/~amathew/SCR.pdf). I will edit my question again to reflect.

Comment: I expect it should be true if $R$ and $S$ are cofibrant and $T$ is fibrant in some simplicial model structure. The usual projective model structure is simplicial and all simplicial algebras are projective-fibrant.